# Prestashop how to extend AdminCarriersController

Tags: php, class, module, controller, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a Carrier module to calculate shipping costs by zipcodes for Prestashop 1.6.

I'm trying to extend the AdminCarriersController but I can't get it.

I know CarrierModule is different of classic or payment modules but it has to be allowed to extend its controller, isn't it?

Here is my code:

```
class AdminEvershippingController extends AdminCarriersController {}
```

Kindly please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok what you are doing can be done like that . i am guessing that your module is Evershipping? if you want to edit a function which is in the AdminCarriersController you need to use override but what you are doing will never work

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway.

I had to build the configuration form in the main php file of the module.